# how to remove part of a string without interrupting a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this but way much bigger

```
df<- structure(list(names = c("bests-1", "trible-1", "crazy-1", "cool-1", 
"nonsense-1", "Mean-1", "Lose-1", "Trye-1", "Trified-1"), Col = c(1L, 
2L, NA, 4L, 47L, 294L, 2L, 1L, 3L), col2 = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

as an example, I am trying to remove -1 from all strings of the first column

I can do this with

```
as.data.frame(str_remove_all(df$names, "-1"))
```

the problem is that it will remove all other columns as well.

I dont want to split the data and merge again because I am afraid I Make a mismatch

Is there anyway without interrupting, just getting raid of specific strings?

for instance the output should looks like this

```
    names Col col2
   bests   1    2
   trible   2    4
   crazy  NA    5
   cool   4    7
 nonsense  47    9
     Mean 294    9
     Lose   2    0
     Try   1    2
  Trified   3    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub`, escape the special `\\-`, and `$` for end of string.

```
transform(df, names=gsub('\\-1$', '', names))
#      names Col col2
# 1    bests   1    2
# 2   trible   2    4
# 3    crazy  NA    5
# 4     cool   4    7
# 5 nonsense  47    9
# 6     Mean 294    9
# 7     Lose   2    0
# 8     Trye   1    2
# 9  Trified   3    3
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(names = c("bests-1", "trible-1", "crazy-1", "cool-1", 
"nonsense-1", "Mean-1", "Lose-1", "Trye-1", "Trified-1"), Col = c(1L, 
2L, NA, 4L, 47L, 294L, 2L, 1L, 3L), col2 = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: I liked it Jay but for someone who less knows of characteristics for gsub I prefer something simpler ! Thanks

Comment: @nik You may also do `transform(df, names=gsub('-1', '', names))`, but it's safer if there are `-1` within a string, i.e. not just at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` package,

```
df$names = str_remove_all(df$names, '-1')

     names Col col2
1    bests   1    2
2   trible   2    4
3    crazy  NA    5
4     cool   4    7
5 nonsense  47    9
6     Mean 294    9
7     Lose   2    0
8     Trye   1    2
9  Trified   3    3
```

Comment: @ I liked it, I dont know how I could miss this! seriously sometimes we go crazy about everything and then forget the solution is in front of us. thanks

Comment: Yeah, it sure does happen.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$names <- trimws(df$names, whitespace = "-\\d+")
```

-output

```
> df
     names Col col2
1    bests   1    2
2   trible   2    4
3    crazy  NA    5
4     cool   4    7
5 nonsense  47    9
6     Mean 294    9
7     Lose   2    0
8     Trye   1    2
9  Trified   3    3
```

Comment: thanks, I am not that familiar with this function